# How to solve a trinomial factor with a method or algorithm?

Tags: factoring

For factor a expression like:

$x^2 + px + q$, we need to use: $(x + a)(x + b), p = a  + b, q = ab$

Ok, I know and I understand how to do it.

Sure, it's easy to get for low values, with error and test, but how for high values ? What algorithms exist for this ( instead of trying infinitely)?

Comment: look into quadratic formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the quadratic formula you can apply for your case:

$$a = \frac{p - \sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}$$

$$b = \frac{p + \sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}$$

But, that isn't necessarily faster than ones you can "see" like $x^2+5x+6$ (where it's clear that $2+3=5;2\cdot 3=6$).